# Read ViewData Sub Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewdata

**Q: How can I get this ViewData? `@ViewData["MyCustomCollection"]["MyParam1"]` it returns the error`Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`**

View (MyCustomCollecion has `[UIHint("MyCustomEditor")]`

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyCustomCollection, new
{
    MyCustomCollection = new
    {
        Param1 = "MyParam1"
        Param2 = "MyParam2"
    }
})
```

MyCustomEditor

```
(...)
<span>@ViewData["MyCustomCollection"]["MyParam1"]<span>
<span>@ViewData["MyCustomCollection"]["MyParam2"]<span>
(...)
```

**Important: I need to set `MyCustomCollection` as a parent. I cannot do this:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyCustomCollection, new
{
   Param1 = "MyParam1"
   Param2 = "MyParam2"
})
```

Comment: You binding to a property named `MyCustomCollection` but then also passing an object named `MyCustomCollection` as `additionalViewData` which does not really make sense. What is your model, in particular the `MyCustomCollection` property

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need to use the same `EditorTemplate` to many properties with different Param1 and . So, the property name passed is a way to identify which editor should be handle by the template. I also would do something like `MyCustomCollection_Param1`, `AnotherCustomCollection_Param1`, but I'm trying to make something cleaner.

Comment: Again, that is not making sense, in particular your edit where you state _I cannot do this_ as you already binding to `MyCustomCollection`

Comment: @StephenMuecke alright, so how do I say to my `EditorTemplate` that the `Param1` refers to MyCustomCollection or AnotherCustomCollection? If I have 3 properties using this same EditorTamplate in the same view, and get  the Param1 doing `ViewData["Param1"]` what's going to happen?

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyCustomCollection)` mean your binding to a property named `MyCustomCollection`. Why do you think you need to override all that by sending another different object named `MyCustomCollection` to the template as additional view data. Without knowing your model, and what it is your actually editing, its difficult to understand what you trying to do here

Comment: @StephenMuecke simply because I have the same EditorTemplate used in more than one property, and **it has some controls inside it that needs additional parameters** to be configured, in which will depend on the property is using it and the only way to get this parameters from EditorTemplate that I know is using ViewData/ViewBag.

Comment: I would do it from the `EditorTamplate` retrieving the property name using `ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("")` and then concatenating with the params. In this case my params would have to be named like `MyCustomCollection_Param1` - that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's possible to do what I was trying to, following this approach.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045595/3880331