# Read object values in Razor

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a ViewData that contains a string like that.

```
{ Param1 = "1", Param2 = "2", Param3 = "3" }
```

I'm setting it to an object razor variable, but I can't read this values like @myVar.Param1.

```
@{
    object myParameters = ViewData["parameters"];
}
```

I know how to do that in JS, but not in Razor. What is the best way to do this?

Regards

Comment: When you say "contains a string", you mean you are setting the view data like so? `ViewData["parameters"] = "{ Param1 = \"1\", Param2 = \"2\", Param3 = \"3\" }";`

Comment: @AaronLS ViewData is set like this (I have no access to change) `new { parameters = new { Param1 = "1", Param2 = "2", Param3 = "3" } }`. Reading from the View it's like you typed with no the bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using object of anonymous type defined elsewhere (in controller), you cannot have strong typed access to the properties. However you should be able to use Eval:

```
ViewData.Eval("parameters.Param1")
```

Although I encourage you to consider defining a class for this model.

Answer (score 1):

myParameters should be dynamic:

`dynamic myParameters = ViewData["parameters"];`

Comment: I tried this approach but nothing changed compared setting my variable as object.